# "There is somebody" + verbing or + to verb?

Tags: grammar, participle-clauses

I looked up "there is somebody" in Corpus and found two sentences

> 1. In short, unless **there is somebody willing to take** the risk of
>    speaking up for it....
> 2. **there is somebody to protect** the reputation of each defendant
>    who is in the court...

I understand the first sentence has omitted "who is", that's the reason for using "willing", but I can't analyse the structure of the second sentence. Can you please help me to understand the use of "there is/are sbody/sth".

Answer (score 0):

"... there is someone to protect the reputation of ..."
"... there exists someone who can protect the reputation of ..."

It might be "will protect" instead of "can protect".

Comment: "There exists someone [whose job it is] to protect..." Depending on context, you could substitute _whose role in life it is_, as in the song "Someone to watch over me".